# Toggle switch won't return primary theme on second click

Tags: javascript, html

At first click it change the theme, but when I click 2nd time, nothing happen, like it's forever the second theme.  So it should change theme on every click. Can anyone give me a hand, please.

```js
let element = document.getElementById('body');
let toggle = document.getElementById('toggle-button');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (element.className == 'dark') {
        element.className = 'light';
    } else {
        element.className = 'light';
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: auto 165px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #20222F 25%, #1D2128 75%);
}

.dark {
  background: black;
}

.light {
  background: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-button" id="toggle-button">
  <span>Dark Mode</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox" class="label">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to refer to the class and the body tag as an id - `document.getElementById`. And I replaced your `if` conditions with the `toggle() method`, specifying the color `burlywood` in it, since your body already has a `black` color by default.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('body');
let toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  element.classList.toggle('light')
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin: auto 165px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #20222F 25%, #1D2128 75%);
}

/*.dark {
  background: black;
}*/

.light {
  background: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-button" id="toggle-button">
  <span>Dark Mode</span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox" class="label">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```